# In Broadcast receiver class, onReceive method contains custom intent which is not working in Samsung mobile

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

Here i am trying to build a simple sms receiving app. In Broadcast receiver class,
I have the `onReceive` method which contains a custom intent which is not working in Samsung Mobile(4.1.2) but it works in kitkat 4.4(moto e).

```
 Intent in = new Intent("SmsMessage.intent.MAIN").putExtra("get_body", sms_body);                               
 context.sendBroadcast(in);
```

How do I do this in Android 4.1.2?

Comment: Please help me anybody. I am new to android and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: This is a full tutorial. If you still are facing a problem after making sure you implemented every single step in this tutorial, please post the whole code :http://javapapers.com/android/android-receive-sms-tutorial/

Comment: Sorry Broadcast receiver class in jar. I am calling its from jar. I want send sms body Broadcast receiver class to other app actvity.

Comment: We;; I believe that it is better if you actually implement the broadcast receiver yourself without using a jar

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do if send some data via an intent right?

If no please do explain what you mean by broadcast not working.

If yes the put the following inside your `onReceive()` method.

```
Intent in = new Intent(context, ****Name of your activity****.class)

in.putExtra("get_body", sms_body)

context.startActivity(in);
```

**Please do take note that where I have mentioned _****Name of your activity****_change it to the name of your activity**

Inside your activity create a method `onNewIntent ()`

Inside which input the following code:

```
String textInSms = intent.getStringExtra("get_body")
```

That's it now you can do whatever you want with the textInSms string. It holds the value of whatever extra you passed to it.

Comment: Hope it solves your issue. If so please let me know. Also if there is something wrong or anything else you need to know let me know.

Comment: Sorry Broadcast receiver class in jar. I am calling its from jar. I want send sms body from Broadcast receiver class to other app actvity.

Comment: Ok slow is this other app yours or some other app I highly recommend not using broadcast receivers from jar's you can still send an intent to another app via just normal intents

Comment: Ok.. Thank you KISHORE_ZE.  Broadcast receiver class in jar. I am calling its from jar. I want send SMS body from Broadcast receiver class to other app actvity. I have requirement like this. May be now it is difficult for us to know about it..